# Как связать javascript с изображением координатной оси

Tags: javascript

Есть input для чисел, под ним картинка оси. Как через javascript привязать точки к этой картинке, чтобы появлялись те, которые соответствуют введенному числу? Хотелось бы понять как, через какие функции это сделать в общем, без привязки к конкретной картинке.

Comment: "Есть ... картинка оси" - что это означает - известно только Вам.

Comment: Поскольку вопрос общий - дам обший совет. Используйте canvas.

Answer (score 2):

в image.onload вы узнаёте размер картинки. При этом картинку оборачиваете например в `<div style="position:relative">`. Далее при вводе значений ставите точку в виде например того же `<div style="position:absolute;left:inputvaluex;top:inputvaluey">`.
Всё тоже самое вы можете проделать с тегом `map,canvas,svg` в зависимости от задачи.